# Screen goes blank (black) for a few seconds when (Ubuntu) dual monitor setup

Tags: gnome, display, monitors, bell

The laptop and monitor screen (connected via hdmi) goes blank.
example:

- when autocomplete in terminal fails
- when taking a screenshot

I believe the OS is trying to play a notification sound but it is failing to do so.

The audio is working fine.

Laptop specs:

[image]

```
$ dmesg -l err
[    0.225931] x86/cpu: VMX (outside TXT) disabled by BIOS
[    0.225941] x86/cpu: SGX disabled by BIOS.
[    0.380562] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.RP03.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[    0.380603] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP03.PC01._ON due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[    0.440228] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.RP03.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[    0.440265] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP03.PC01._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[   19.777581] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT, Index (0x00000004B) is beyond end of object (length 0x44) (20210331/exoparg2-393)
[   19.777656] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WHCM due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20210331/psparse-529)
[   19.777674] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.WMID.WMAA due to previous error (AE_AML_PACKAGE_LIMIT) (20210331/psparse-529)
[ 5934.030523] i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* CPU pipe B FIFO underrun
[11419.226593] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._PPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[11419.226643] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PTS due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[11420.273090] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.RP03.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[11420.273134] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP03.PC01._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[15439.063104] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:0e.0: azx_get_response timeout, switching to single_cmd mode: last cmd=0x20bf8100
[15439.361819] snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: Unable to sync register 0x2f0d00. -5
[15439.926958] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[15439.927318] snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: Unable to sync register 0x2b8000. -5
[24227.045287] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._PPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[24227.045346] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PTS due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[24227.849375] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.RP03.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[24227.849436] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP03.PC01._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[24349.016510] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._PPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[24349.016564] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PTS due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[24350.287650] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.RP03.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[24350.287694] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP03.PC01._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[27414.886509] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_PR.CPU0._PPC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[27414.886566] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_PTS due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
[27415.918488] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.RP03.PEGP.TDGC], AE_NOT_FOUND (20210331/psargs-330)
[27415.918530] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.RP03.PC01._OFF due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20210331/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Do checkout https://askubuntu.com/a/324286/115115